# How can i change the default database for simple membership tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, connection-string, simplemembership, localdb

I would like to ask this quick question about the default simple membership database that comes with asp.net mvc 4.5 internet application , my question is about where does it create its tables when I first create new user does it create its table in the default connection string (LocalDB) ? and what if I changed the default connection string to use a custom MS SQL Express database will that get reflected and those tables will be created in my new database ?

i noticed this code in the default account model and in its DbContext class it refers to default connection this was the code there :

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

SimpleMembership gets initialised in the `InitializeSimpleMemberhsipAttribute.cs` class.

In the default MVC 4 internet project template, navigate to the Filters directory, and in the above class you'll find the initialising method:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile",
 "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

That's the default setup, if you want to point it at a different database do something like this:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyContext", "TableToPointTo", 
"UserIdColumn", "UserNameColumn", autoCreateTables: false);
```

In your context class:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext {...}
```

And change the name in the connection strings section inside the `<configuration>` section in the root `web.config` file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContext" connectionString="..." />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Or just change the settings for the DefaultConnection connection string in the web.config.

Comment: Would you not need to change the first parameter in InitialiseDatabaseConnection() too - in order to "change the default database for simple membership tables" as OP asked?

Comment: The first parameter is the name of the connection string. You could keep it as "DefaultConnection" and just change the value of connectinString.  If you change the name of the connection string you need to make sure that you also change it in the constructor for the DbContext.

Comment: Understood. Well, if he ever logs in again, at least he'll know a little more than he did.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking into this thread since I was facing the same issue. I had tried all the steps like -

- Granting permission to SQLServer
- Removing the [InitializeSimpleMembership] attribute for account controller along with adding WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection connection in Global.asax.

But nothing worked.

So tried something else -

- Changed the Data Source in the default connection string to localhost.
- Created an empty DB in the localhost named as MVCApp
- Set the initial catalog in the connection string to MVCApp
- Removed the AttachDBFilename from the connection string

So now my connection string points to a local database. And it worked.

I am still not sure why the default implementation by MS that had been working just couple of days back is not working as of now. But at this point of time I am happy with work around.